# KnockoutJS cannot delete object from observableArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
var testVM = {
  things: ko.observableArray([
    { id: 1, name: "Apple" },
    { id: 2, name: "Banana" },
    { id: 3, name: "Orange" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pineapple" },
    { id: 5, name: "Pear" }
    ]),

  deleteThing: function (data) {
    var things = testVM.things;
    var index = things.indexOf(data);

    // Debug...
    console.log('data', data);
    console.log('index', index);

    if (index > -1) {
        things.splice(index, 1)
    }
  },

  deleteApple: function () {
    this.deleteThing({ id: 1, name: "Apple" });
  }

};

ko.applyBindings(testVM);
```

With the HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: things">
  <li>
    <a data-bind="click: $root.deleteThing">X</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<a data-bind="click: deleteApple">Delete Apple</a>
```

Which I've created in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5Rkj/2/). The issue I'm having is that when invoked from a `data-bind="click: deleteThing"` inside a `foreach` the `deleteThing` function works fine, however if (in the case of the `deleteApple` method) I attempt to manually delete something it never finds the index and subsequently doesn't delete the item from the `observableArray`.

I'm stumped because in both instances the `console.log` shows the same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you are having is related to object references. In your `deleteApple` function you are passing a new object that does not match the original object reference.

The `remove` API does accept a function that passes the item in where you can return truthy/falsy whether you want to remove the item.

Example of using `remove` on an observableArray:

```
deleteApple: function () {
    this.things.remove(function(item) {
       return item.id === 1 && item.name === "Apple";   
    });
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/5HPxZ/

Comment: Thanks Ryan, knew I'd see you here :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you try to delete an object that is not in the array:

```
this.deleteThing({ id: 1, name: "Apple" });
```

Although the values of the properties is the same, the objects are different. Objects are references and you need the correct reference, ie you need the find the index of the item and then delete at that index:

```
for(var i = 0;i<testVM.things.length;i++){
    if(testVM.things[i].id === 1){
        things.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

To test what I mean about references, try and execute the following code:

```
var x = { id: 1, name: "Apple" };
var y = { id: 1, name: "Apple" };
alert(x === y): // Alerts false
```